# How can I crawl requests with JavaScript code, using Python's requests library?

Tags: python, web-crawler

I have a question.
I'm having a problem while crawling requests.
href = "javascript:fnView('./view.do', 2023034722);"
The href is in javascript code.
Not with a library like selenium, but with a library like requests.
Is it possible to run that code and get the html?

I've searched the library over and over, asked GPT, Bard, etc. but I don't see an answer.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Do you want to execute javascript code with python ?